# Get top n related tags to a given tag in a given period

Tags: feature-request, tags, data-explorer

One can use different programming languages for Android app development and I am choosing which to learn. Of course, I want to learn a popular language with a big community and I think the number of posts on SO are a good indicator for this. Thus, my question is: Is there a way to find out which tags were used most frequently with the tag [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android)? So what I am looking for will have the form "[javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) *x* times used with [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android), [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) *y* times used with [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android), ...". Further, to take into consideration the time aspect, can this search be limited to the last year, for example?

Side note: You may find the number of posts a bad indicator for what is a good programming language. Still, I wonder how one technically could find out with which other tag [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) was used most often.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let me try a different approach. We count how often the combination of tags is used on questions. That will show how a combination of tags is commonly used which can learn us more about interesting topics.

Here is the somewhat [rough query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1736292?tagname=android&year=1) (don't pay attention to its revision history) (I think I'm over counting rows but I can't find where):

```sql
declare @tagid integer = (select id from tags where tagname = ##tagname:string##)
declare @years integer = ##year:int?1##

;with postswithtag as (
  select pt.postid, p2.tagid
  from posttags pt
  inner join posts p on p.id = pt.postid
  inner join posttags p2 
     on p2.postid = pt.postid 
    and p2.tagid <> @tagid
  where pt.tagid = @tagid
  and p.creationdate between dateadd(yy, -@years, getdate()) and getdate()
)

select cnt [Number of Posts]
     , t1.tagname
     , t2.tagname
     , t3.tagname
     , t4.tagname
     , t5.tagname
from (
  select count(distinct postid) [cnt], [1], [2], [3], [4], [5]
  from(
    select postid, [1], [2], [3], [4], [5]
    from (
      select tagid
           , postid
           , row_number() over(partition by postid order by count desc) [row]
      from postswithtag pt
      inner join tags t on t.id = pt.tagid
    ) data
    pivot (
       min(tagid) 
       for row in ( [1], [2], [3], [4], [5])
    ) pvt
  ) total
  group by [1],[2],[3],[4],[5]
) tag_cols
inner join tags t1 on t1.id = [1]
left outer join tags t2 on t2.id = [2]
left outer join tags t3 on t3.id = [3]
left outer join tags t4 on t4.id = [4]
left outer join tags t5 on t5.id = [5]
order by cnt desc
```

When run today this is the result for the Android tag:

[image: tables with count and 5 columns with tag names]

So this should tell you the frequency of the combination of tags in posts tagged with Android. Give or take counting errors.

Comment: Arguably you could drop [5]. You're excluding the tag you're searching for so there's a max of 4 (remaining) tags that can be on a question (not really impacting the results, just a little bit of extra work there.)

Comment: @HenryEcker yeah, in an ideal world. Welcome to Stack Overflows data management: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1736820

Comment: Well then it looks like you're missing a [6] and [7] column xD

Answer (score 7):

Yes. Use [the Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow).

Here ya go :D

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1735629/sibling-tag-counts-for-a-given-tag-in-the-past-365-days?tagname=android

```sql
DECLARE @tagname NVARCHAR(MAX) = ##tagname:string##
DECLARE @tagid INT = (SELECT T.Id FROM Tags T WHERE T.TagName = @tagname)

SELECT
  MAX(T.TagName) AS Name,
  COUNT(PT.TagId) AS Count
FROM Posts Q
JOIN PostTags PT ON PT.PostId = Q.Id
JOIN Tags T ON T.Id = PT.TagId
WHERE
  Q.PostTypeId = 1
  AND Q.CreationDate > DATEADD(year, -1, getdate())
  AND Q.Tags like '%<'+@tagname+'>%'
  AND PT.TagId <> @tagid
GROUP BY PT.TagId
--HAVING COUNT(PT.TagId) > 5
ORDER BY COUNT(PT.TagId) DESC
;
```

Top few results from last SEDE refresh that time of this writing:

| tag name | count |
| --- | --- |
| kotlin | 11455 |
| java | 9697 |
| flutter | 5300 |
| android-studio | 4985 |
| android-jetpack-compose | 3447 |
| react-native | 3024 |
| firebase | 2823 |
| dart | 2067 |
| ios | 1796 |
| gradle | 1784 |
| android-recyclerview | 1477 |
| android-layout | 1112 |
| xml | 1082 |
| firebase-realtime-database | 902 |
| android-fragments | 898 |
| javascript | 889 |
| android-room | 705 |
| google-cloud-firestore | 689 |
| mobile | 680 |
| google-play | 666 |
| c# | 649 |

The magic-8 ball says you should [learn some Kotlin](https://developer.android.com/kotlin).

Comment: Actually java is not that far off and then  there is a big drop.. Thanks for that!

Answer (score 5):

As already answered, Data Explorer will give you the most in-depth information here, but the simple all-time sibling tag stats are available on the lower right-hand side of every tag-only question search page, under [the "Related Tags" heading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android#h-related-tags):

[image: Related Tags for Java]

(It even shows up for [multi-tag searches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android+kotlin#h-related-tags)!)